# How to lock text in Facebook share button in swift?

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, button, share

I am trying to implement share button in my spritekit swift game. It works well but I don't know how to lock the text, so user can't change it before posting to facebook. Thanks for any help.

my code looks like this:

```
func shareToFacebook() {

    var sharetoface : SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
    sharetoface.setInitialText("My score was \(score)")

    let vc: UIViewController = self.view!.window!.rootViewController!
    vc.presentViewController(sharetoface, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: _“so user can't change it before posting to facebook”_ – you are not allowed to pre-fill the message part of a post in any way, it has to be a 100% user generated, i.e. typed in by the user. You should go read Platform Policies.

Comment: I am aware of that, but I want users to post their highscore and if they are able to put whatever they want it kinda loses the point...

Comment: Well, that still doesn’t justify violating policies. You are simply not allowed to post their highscore as the message part of a post. Either use the Scores API for games, or publish Open Graph objects that carry that data in their title/description.

Answer (score 0):

`SLComposeViewController` is a subclass of `UIViewController` so it has a view associated with it. So you can at first get the view of `SLComposeViewController` just by calling its property `view` on it and search the subviews of that view using `view.subviews` and find TextField. Then you can set the UITextField instance's enabled property to false.

```
func shareToFacebook() {

    var sharetoface : SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
    sharetoface.setInitialText("My score was \(score)")

    /* New code added */
    let view = sharetofave.view as! UIView // as! Forced unwrapped as of Swift 1.2 ß3 

    let subviews = view.subviews

    let textField: UITextField // no need to initialize let constants as soon as possible as of Swift 1.2 ß3

    for v in subviews {
      if v is UITextField {
        textField = v as! UITextField
      }
    }

    textField.enabled = false
    /* New code added */

    let vc: UIViewController = self.view!.window!.rootViewController!
    vc.presentViewController(sharetoface, animated: true, completion: nil)

}


// Using SLComposeServiceViewController 
func newShareToFacebook() {
        var sharetoface : SLComposeServiceViewController = SLComposeServiceViewController()

        sharetoface.textView.text = "My score was \(score)"

        sharetoface.textView.enabled = false

        let vc: UIViewController = self.view!.window!.rootViewController!
        vc.presentViewController(sharetoace, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: thanks for you reply, I tried to implement it, but the subviews variable is empty, so I can't search for a TextField in it...

Comment: @tommhol try newShareToFacebook() method that I added to my previous answer. It uses SLComposeServiceViewController instead of SLComposeViewController